# Multiple representations of the same entity Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring Boot App with Hibernate as JPA provider and model mapper dependency. The scene it's simple, I have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contracts", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateContract(@DTO(ContractUpdateDto.class) Contract contract,
            UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        if(contract!=null) {
            contract.getWork().setState(contract.getState()); //Problematic code that causes the exception
            contractService.updateContract(contract);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

    }
```

The mapping that I have It's the following:

**Work**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="work")
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class Work implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="id_work")
    private int id;

    Some preoperties.....


    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "work", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Contract contract;

}
```

**Contract**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contract")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Contract {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="id_contract")
    private int id;

    Some properties.....

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_contract$milestone", nullable=false)
    private Set<Milestone> milestones;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_work$contract")
    private Work work;
}
```

**Milestone**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="milestone")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Milestone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="id_milestone")
    private int id;

    Some properties...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_item$milestone")
    private Item item;

}
```

**Item**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="item")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name="id_item")
    private int id;

    Some properties...
}
```

DTO's:

```
@Getter
public class ContractUpdateDto {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String clarifications;

    private State state;

    private double subtotal;

    private double administrationFee;

    private Double totalValue;

    private Set<MilestoneUpdateDto> milestones;

}

@Getter
public class MilestoneUpdateDto {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private State state;

    private ItemUpdateDto item;
}

@Getter
public class ItemUpdateDto {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private double value;

    private double durationValue;

    private String durationTime;

    private double warrantyValue;

    private String warrantyTime;

    private String workDescription;

    private String warrantyDescription;

    private String imageContract;

    private String commentContract;
}
```

The problem occurs when I send a JSON object that contains a contract with a list of milestones, where every milestone has an Item object. Like that:

```
{"id":16,
"contractNumber":"TEIXSK",
"creationDate":1534772800000,
"state":"CONTRACT_MODIFIED_BY_PROVIDER",
"subtotal":211221,
"administrationFee":10561,
"totalValue":221782,
"milestones":[{"id":15,"state":"CREATED",
"item":{
"id":8,
"name":"Nueva Prueba",
"value":211221,
"durationValue":2,
"durationTime":"Mes(es)",
"warrantyValue":2,
"warrantyTime":"Año(s)",
"workDescription":"sads",
"warrantyDescription":"sdsad",
"imageContract":"data:image/jpeg;base64",
"commentContract":"añadido"}}],
"clarifications":"añadido"
}
```

After sending the mentioned object, I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same
>   entity [com.espiritware.opusclick.model.Item#8] are being merged.
>   Detached: [com.espiritware.opusclick.model.Item@530a9998]; Detached:
>   [com.espiritware.opusclick.model.Item@78eae981]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.EntityCopyNotAllowedObserver.entityCopyDetected(EntityCopyNotAllowedObserver.java:37)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.MergeContext.put(MergeContext.java:256)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:304)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:850)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:832)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$6.cascade(CascadingActions.java:260)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:431)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:363)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:468)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at

My question is why this happens, what this exception refers to in this case..because if I comment this line in my controller:

```
contract.getWork().setState(contract.getState());
```

The problem disappears, everything works perfectly....My question is why this behavior occurs when doing the commented
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Can you add work entity

Comment: Yes, I will update my question

Comment: Hey you are not showing what `updateContract` does.

Comment: @Antoniossss I update my question

Comment: Can multiple works have the same items? It looks like some works would have duplicating items with the same ID, but beeing separate instances.

Comment: You have two different detached entities with the `id` 8, so at merge time Hibernate throws an error since it doesn't know which one is the correct one.

Comment: @Antoniossss Can multiple works have the same items? The Answer it's Yes!

Comment: So thats the problem. You deserialized JSON to entity graph but there is no concept of managed instances there - thus you have multiple (3 to be exact) different instances pretending to represent the same entity.

Comment: @Antoniossss but I do not know where two item entities are coming from, I will update my question showing how my model looks in database

Comment: I only assume that it comes from DTO - doesn't it ?

Comment: @Antoniossss Update my question with the DTOs that I use

Comment: You got items in milestones and there must be some duplicates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178468/discussion-between-alejodev-and-antoniossss).

Comment: @Antoniossss Forgive me, but I still do not understand, what happens if I send the Milestones with the Items, if these are part of the modification I am making. How I can deserialized JSON to entity graph as managed instance?

Comment: I don't think you can do it out of the box.

Comment: @Antoniossss Why I have multiple (3 to be exact) different instances pretending to represent the same entity. Can you tell me why you say this? Thanks!

Comment: Thats what exception says.

Comment: @Antoniossss Why if I comment this line on my controller: **contract.getWork().setState(contract.getState());**  it works without problems. what is the explanation of this ... the exception is not generated

Comment: All this code just to ask about a simple error? "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity" says you have two detached entities. Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @K.Nicholas the question is simple, why the exception appears when I do not comment this line: *contract.getWork().setState(contract.getState());* 
If the answer is so simple, what is it?

Comment: The error says that both entities are detached. Without getting into it I'm pretty sure you can't merge two detached entities. It certainly doesn't make sense. A detached entity is no longer part of a transaction, so where is JPA going to save the result? Seems to me you need to understand that part first. Much as I'd like to help you I'm certainly not going through 3 pages of code to figure out what your bug/confusion is.

Comment: @AlejoDev probably cascade wont happen then.